# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.gmavenplus:gmavenplus-plugin:1.9.0:compile (default) on project: Error occurred while calling a method

Tags: java, groovy, junit

We have test cases written in both groovy and java, either groovy test cases or java test cases are getting executed,not both.If we provide configuration on gmavenplus-plugin for both java and groovy.If we add sources and dependency for groovy-all as below
In pom:

```
            <plugin>
            <!-- Compiles Groovy code. -->
            <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>compileTests</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>
                        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/groovy</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.groovy</include>
                        </includes>
                    </source>
                    <source>
                        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </source>
                </sources>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4.9</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <!-- Run Spock Tests -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <useFile>false</useFile>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                    <version>2.19.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1-groovy-2.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

`<dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Test cases are failing with error "[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.gmavenplus:gmavenplus-plugin:1.9.0:compile (default) on project: Error occurred while calling a method on a Groovy class from classpath.: InvocationTargetException: junit/framework/TestCase: junit.framework.TestCase